# Is it possible to block all websites except one website on an android programmatically?

Tags: android, browser, block

Is there any way of blocking websites pro grammatically on an Android device if user open any browser in his devise. actually my requirement is i have one website only that website will open in a browser, except that website if any website if user open that should not open(blocked) it shows some alert.please any one solve my problem.

Comment: yes we can block. you need to run the service and read the log cat message frequently when your browser trigger other web pages you can show alert.

Comment: thanks Mr.Padma kumar i am new to this topic can u provide any sample code

Answer (score 1):

Yes. I finally found a way to do it.

Download kiwi browser from [play store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kiwibrowser.browser).

With this browser you can add chrome extensions on Android.
Then, download the `stayfocusd` extension from the [chrome store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stayfocusd/laankejkbhbdhmipfmgcngdelahlfoji)

Go to the extension settings, and you can use it to block any site you want (and allow some, of course).
But, instead of blocking all the sites you don't want one by one, I found a way to block ALL websites on the internet by adding ONE blocked site - `https://`.
After you've added `https://` to your blocked sites list, simply add your site(s) that you want to allow in the `Allowed sites` list, and that's it!

P.S. there is also the `Nuclear option` in the extension settings that lets you block all sites except the allowed ones, but unfortunately this option doesn't work on android...

There is another browser know as yandex browser . where you can use the nuclear option.
There is also `Max time allowed` option in this extension, so you can set how much time you want to use the blocked sites before the extension blocks them.
Unfortunately you can't change the time to more than what it currently is after you set it on Android...

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot do that until you have special application or proxy setup.

You can have to install proxy server on android and you can control which website to open or not.

[Try proxoid](http://code.google.com/p/proxoid/)